# Dynamic filter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm working with PHP, SQL and other back-end languages. My client wants to get a dynamic filter on his site. I found a script on Internet but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.results > td').hide();

  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > td').hide();
    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.results > td.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box col-md-12 items tags">
  <ul>
    <li class="head">Producent</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent1" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw Promise" rel="Promise" />Promise</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent2" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw NetStor" rel="NetStor" />NetStor</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent3" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw Stardom" rel="Stardom" />Stardom</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent4" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw LaCie" rel="LaCie" />LaCie</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent5" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw G-Tech" rel="G-Tech" />G-Tech</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent6" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw mLogic" rel="mLogic" />mLogic</li>
    <li>
      <input id="producent7" type="checkbox" class="szukajnapraw Tiger Technology" rel="Tiger Technology" />Tiger Technology</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Table:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Producent</th>
                <th>Produkt</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Typ</th>
                <th>Cena netto</th>
                <th>Cena brutto</th>
                <th>Interface</th>
                <th>Ilość dysków</th>
                <th>Pojemność</th>
                <th>RAID</th>
                <th>Wydajność</th>
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Specyfikacja</th>
                <th>Zakup</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
 
            <tbody class="results">
            <tr> <td>Tiger Technology</td><td>Macierz 123 TEST</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/ff.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>NAS Network Attached Storage</td><td>69.00</td><td>124.00</td><td>Thunderbolt2</td><td>60</td><td>5tb</td><td>0 1</td><td>Duża</td><td>dsadsadasdawderwasfcagfae</td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='30' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Stardom</td><td>dsa</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td></td><td>1.00</td><td>1.00</td><td></td><td>4</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href=http://www.facebook.com target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='31' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>G-Tech</td><td>vcxv</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>USB 3.0</td><td>5</td><td>400</td><td>5*5*</td><td>500</td><td>dsadsad</td><td><a href=http://www.o2.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='34' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Tiger Technology</td><td>das sad</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/IMG_20150504_074450.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>eSATA</td><td>6</td><td>400</td><td>5/8/8</td><td>500</td><td>dasdasdsa</td><td><a href=http://www.nw.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='35' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>LaCie</td><td>Macierz</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>98.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>miniSAS</td><td>6</td><td>4 TB</td><td>5</td><td>Duża</td><td>Tu powinien być opis, ale testuje i go nie wpisuje! </td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='36' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>LaCie</td><td>dsad</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/IMG_20150504_074450.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>400</td><td>8/8/8</td><td>500</td><td>fasdf</td><td><a href=http://fsdfsdf target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='37' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>mLogic</td><td>test</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/ff.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>80.00</td><td>100.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>900</td><td>5/8/8</td><td>600</td><td>fsdfd</td><td><a href=http://fsdfds target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='38' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr> <td>Promise</td><td>Zdjęcie</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>4564.00</td><td>999999.99</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>300</td><td>SPrawdzam czy działaja fotki .... .... .. .. .. .</td><td><a href=http://feasd target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='39' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr>            </tbody>
            </table>
```

If the checkbox is checked, I want to show the his rel or value. I also need to show only table cells where "Producent" is rel.

How can I do this?

Comment: HTML for `.results`?

Comment: I've edited your post to take advantage of the code snippet feature of Stack Overflow, which allows you much the same functionality of jsfiddle without the external link.

Comment: HTML for results is a table generated by PHP in tbody.

Comment: Even if it's dynamically generated server side, that's fine. Based on your included code, it would be necessary to give you any answer that would be useful. As it is, without the output of your server side code it's not possible to answer.

Comment: where is your `table html`??

Comment: So post generated HTML, without it it doesn't make sense even to try helping you. You can see yourself, jQuery question, asked 12 mins ago and no answer? Hence, something is wrong with the question.

Comment: @patwoj98 in the browser go to view source and get the html for the table

Comment: Ok, I try to include it.

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z5kcpL4/3/ I made a guess how yours html table looks like.

Comment: The table which PHP generate is in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the contents of the first td, not the class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.results > tr').hide();

    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        $('.results > tr').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.results > tr').has('td:first-child:contains("' + $(this).attr('rel')+'")').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3x5jfjg/1)

---

But a better solution will be is to change the markup so that the tr element will have the value as an attribute value like `<tr data-producent="G-Tech">`

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.results > tr').hide();

    $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
        $('.results > tr').hide();
        $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function () {
            $('.results > tr[data-producent="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '"]').show();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3x5jfjg/5/)

Comment: It's work! :) But if there aren't checboxes checked, there aren't info is showed. How to show all producents where are checboxes no checked?

Comment: So, I need it in td cause there will be more search types. Can someone write the same what Arun but with td?

Comment: @patwoj98 sorry.. .do you want the same with the first version?

Comment: @patwoj98 the column to be searched is 7 here... in the previous case it was 4 - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f3x5jfjg/12/

Comment: How can we search in columns: 1,4,7 in one script?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajwj7kt9/1/ so, now I do it with range. Range 1 is working with td number 8. Range 2 with number 9. Range 3 with number 11. How can I summary this scripts? Can you help me one more time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77238/discussion-between-patwoj98-and-arun-p-johny).